# Use of Files in Ubuntu Repository Section "Restriced/l"

Tags: system-installation, repository, offline, apt-mirror

In a current Ubuntu repository on the server there is among the main folders in the "pool" section "main" "multiverse", "universe", etc also the folder "restriced". In this "restricted" section the subfolder "l" is quite large, e.g. 78GB for 20.04 focal.
As I use an offline repository created by "apt-mirror" I want to reduce the disk space requirements on the offline server (adding up for multiple versions).

Looking in the folders in the "restriced/l" for 20.04 almost all files have "nvidia" in the name so I think they have somehting to do with graphic drivers. About half the folders are "signature" folders and rather small, but for each "signature" folder there is a "modules" folder with ich rather large. All folders contain almost identical data, and the title variations show those basic types

```
  pool/restriced/l/linux-restricted-modules  
  pool/restriced/l/linux-restricted-modules-aws
  pool/restriced/l/linux-restricted-modules-azure
  pool/restriced/l/linux-restricted-modules-hwe
  pool/restriced/l/linux-restricted-modules-gcp    
  pool/restriced/l/linux-restricted-modules-oem
  pool/restriced/l/linux-restricted-modules-oracle
```

Interesting is also that under "restricted/n" also nvidia drivers are located. That seem to be the orginal nvidia drivers.

My guess is that the modules refer to binary kernel modules for the drivers, but I have no idea when and why they are needed beside the original nvidia driver files in the "n" section. Any graphics driver problem I had over the years only involved those original drivers. Another guess is that the modules are only needed for cloud installations as the names "aws", "azure" suggest. But I do not know what "gcm", hwe", "oem" and "oracle" should refer to. I googled for "linux-restricted-modules" but mainly got file listings and almost no explanations.

**So my question is**: What is the purpose of those files in the restriced/l" section and what are the consequences when I delete them from my offline repository?

Obviously I do not use any clould related services at an offline system. But what about the "linux-restricted-modules" that suggest a generic use, maybe thats needed with any nvidia installation?

**Edit**: I will be using proprietary nvidia drivers, so any relation of those modules to nvidia hardware would be be relevant. Generally I would like to understand what these packages are for and when I would be needing them. I'd rather understand what I delete before I do it.

Answer (score 1):

The official description of the "restricted" software source is "Proprietary drivers for devices".

These are packages that are not open source, but released by hardware vendors under restricted (but free) licenses.  These licenses in general mumble something about not reverse engineering the software and only using it for that vendor's devices.

Usually you would not have anything from restricted on your system unless you had devices that had specific restricted drivers available for them.   So if you have nvidia drivers, presumably you have a corresponding nvidia device in your system that needs them.

If you are manually installing drivers from nvidia rather than using the (extremely similar) proprietary drivers in Ubuntu's restricted repo, then the ones in the repo are basically redundant.

As to what the directories you listed are for -- they are not organized by type or category.  They are organized by package name prefix.   All current linux filesystems have performance issues with directories that contain thousands of files, so the subdirectory tree is broken out purely to break up the files into smaller groups so there are at most hundreds of files per directory.  If you want to know what a specific package is for, you will have to check its description.  Very little more than that can be accurately said about each directory beyond "driver", as there are multiple disjoint things in each directory.

Comment: I see my post missed to say that I will be using restriced nvidia drivers. I will add it. You explain generically what the restricted section is. But my question was what these packages are.

Comment: @CatMan the explanation is exactly that - non-open-source drivers for software that are in the repositories but are not open source.  Unless your systems explicitly *rely* on those drivers, you can remove that section from your offline repository clone.  (Though you may want to consider the repositories DO update regularly, so keeping an offline copy of the repos isn't the best solution in the world)

Comment: @Thomas Ward. Sorry for being so unclear. I mean specifically what are those packages, e.g the nividia AWS stuff. Are these graphics drivers solely used in AWS cloud environments? Why does Oracle  need an own series of Nvidia graphic cards? Which OEMs are the OEM drivers? A graphics OEM is e.g. Asus, but I think it unlikely that this is what those OEM packages are for. Thats the kind of questions I mean with "What are those packages for". A lot more specific than "drivers". Not an article about each but like an explaining headline for each folder.

Comment: First, the things you listed are NOT packages, they are directories containing hundreds of packages.  If you want to know what they are for, you will have to check the description of each package.  The purpose of the directories is so there are hundreds of files in each directory instead of thousands of files in each directory, which causes performance issues.